# StringFilter override not working

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm trying to override the behavior of a `StringFilter` used by a `Grid` . 
The code below doesn't have some functionality, I just want to see if `validateModel` is being called. The thing is, it is not being called ever. On the other hand `onFieldKeyUp` is being called as it should. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using `Sencha GXT 3.1.0` , `GWT 2.6.1` , `Java 1.7`

```
Filter<Record, ?> filter = new StringFilter<Record>(valueProvider)
{
    @Override
    protected void onFieldKeyUp(Event event) 
    {
        Window.alert("onFieldKeyUp");   //--> This is called
        int key = event.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER && field.isValid()) 
        {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            menu.hide(true);

            return;
        }

        super.onFieldKeyUp(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validateModel(Record model) 
    {
        Window.alert("validateModel");   //--> This is NOT called
        String rowValue = getValueProvider().getValue(model);
        rowValue = (rowValue == null) ? "" : rowValue;
        Object filterObject = getValue();
        String filterValue = filterObject == null ? "" : String.valueOf(filterObject);

        if (filterValue.isEmpty() && rowValue.isEmpty()) 
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            //Here I want to put some more code manipulating the filtevalue
            return rowValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put the `filters.setLocal(true);` and `filters.initPlugin(grid);`?

Here is the code I tried and worked:

```
GridFilters<MyRow> filters = new GridFilters<MyRow>();

filters.initPlugin(grid);

StringFilter<MyRow> filter = new StringFilter<MyRow>(nameValueProvider) {
  @Override
  protected boolean validateModel(MyRow model) {
    Window.alert("Hello");
    return super.validateModel(model);
  }
};

filters.addFilter(filter);
filters.setLocal(true);
```

Comment: The setLocal(true) did it for me. Thanks a mil. Upvoted and accepted.